# angular 8 Ngx-Webcam - webcam image upload to Firebase storage

Tags: angular, image, firebase-storage, angular8, webcam-capture

In Angular 8 application I am using  [Ngx-Webcam](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-webcam) to capture the webcam image.
and able to get the image by using `imageAsDataUrl` also able to display on page by using `img` tag
`<img [src]="imgSrc">`

I want to upload same image in firebase storage.please help me how to do it.
I tried

```
this.storage.upload(filePath, imgSrc).snapshotChanges().pipe().subscribe(...
```

but getting this error

```
FirebaseStorageError {code_: "storage/invalid-argument", message_: "Firebase Storage: Invalid argument in `put` at index 0: Expected Blob or File.", serverResponse_: null, name_: "FirebaseError"}
```

Comment: As the error message is saying, you need to provide a Blob or File type object to upload() in order to provide the content.  It won't work if you pass a data URL string.

Comment: agree, but here I need help how to create Image object from path - imageAsDataUrl

Answer (score 4):

you can use like this for JS/TS, to convert the ngx-webcam image to File type:

```
handleCapturedImage(webcamImage: WebcamImage) {
this.webcamImage = webcamImage;
const arr = this.webcamImage.imageAsDataUrl.split(",");
const mime = arr[0].match(/:(.*?);/)[1];
const bstr = atob(arr[1]);
let n = bstr.length;
const u8arr = new Uint8Array(n);
while (n--) {
  u8arr[n] = bstr.charCodeAt(n);
}
const file: File = new File([u8arr], this.imageName, { type: this.imageFormat })
console.log(file);  }
```

Comment: Does this library has upload image from gallery/local storage option ? I want to include this in PWA .

Comment: @NoobCoder, we don't have any inbuilt optionfrom ngx-webcam, as far as i know. i have done "ngx-file-drop" for the same...

Comment: I think this is for web app drag and drop. I want to have upload feature only since it is a PWA app and in mobile we can't have drag and drop. Thanks for your reply.